# Python web scraping: TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, web-scraping

```
url = "https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh135098(v=exchg.150).aspx"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
table = soup.find_all('table', attrs={"responsive": "true"})[0]
for rows in table.find_all('tr')[1]:
    item = []
    for val in rows.find('td'):
        item.append(val.text.strip())
        print (item)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not interable
```

Line 4 refers to `for val in rows.find('td'):`

Comment: what does `rows.find('td')` returns ?

Comment: Line 4 or line 3? `for val in rows.find('td'):` is line 7 in the above code. If you include the *full* traceback, it actually shows you the offending line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `for val in rows.find('td'):` when there's no `td` found in the `rows`, it returns `-1` an `int object` which you are trying to loop, hence the error.

The correct approach:

```
>>> for rows in table.find_all('tr'):
...   item = []
...   for val in rows.find_all('td'):
...     item.append(val.text.strip())
...   print(item)
... 
[]
['Exchange Server 2016 CU5', 'March 21, 2017', '15.01.0845.034']
['Exchange Server 2016 CU4', 'December 13, 2016', '15.01.0669.032']
['Exchange Server 2016 CU3', 'September 20, 2016', '15.01.0544.027']
['Exchange Server 2016 CU2', 'June 21, 2016', '15.01.0466.034']
['Exchange Server 2016CU1', 'March 15, 2016', '15.01.0396.030']
['Exchange Server 2016 RTM', 'October 1, 2015', '15.01.0225.042']
['Exchange Server 2016 Preview', 'July 22, 2015', '15.01.0225.016']
```

Comment: I can be a bonehead sometimes. Thanks sir!